# Undefined symbol in native NodeJS module

Tags: c++, node.js, gcc, compiler-construction, v8

I'm building a native C++ nodejs module. I have developed it in windows and now I want to run it on linux. The compiler finishes successfully. But when I run
`require('smartparser')`, I'm getting the following error:

```
var a = require('smartparser')
Error: .../node_modules/smartparser/build/Release/smartparser.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v86String9NewSymbolEPKci
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

I'm using Debian `(Arch: i386)` with `GCC-4.7`.

Node version: `v0.11.3-pre`

NPM version: `1.3.10`

I'm also getting the following warning:

```
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
```

But after little researched, I found out this is caused by wrong local time.

**EDIT2: Code**

```
{
  "author": "deepsy@gmail.com",
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "smartparser",
      "sources": [ "lib/handler.cpp", "lib/analyzer.cpp", "lib/parser.cpp" ],
          "cflags": [
              "-std=c++11"
          ]

    }
  ]
}
```

Cpp

```
Handle<Value> parseHandler(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;

    bool validArguments = 
        args[0]->IsString() &&
        args[1]->IsString() && 
        args[2]->IsNumber() && 
        args[3]->IsFunction();

    if (!validArguments) {
        return ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
            String::New("Invalid arguments! Pass the arguments in the following order: {string} text, {string} title, {int} outputlength, {function} callback.")));
    }

    Local<Array> nodes = Parser(std::string(*String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString())),
                                std::string(*String::Utf8Value(args[1]->ToString())), 
                                int(args[2]->Int32Value()));

    const unsigned argc = 2;
    Local<Value> argv[argc] = {
        Local<Value>::New(Null()),
        nodes
    };

    Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[3]);

    callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), argc, argv);

    return Undefined();
}

Local<Array> Parser(std::string input, std::string title, int sentenceLimit)
{
    Local<Array> nodes = Array::New();
    Local<Object> node_obj;

    std::size_t pos = 0;
    std::size_t closePos = -1;
    std::size_t openPos = -1;

    int tagID = -1;
    int lastTag = -1;
    int lastAppended = -1;

    // Output array iterator
    int id = 0;

    while ((pos = input.find('<', pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        pos++;
        switch (tagID = tagDetect(&input[pos])) {

        case Tags::Closing:

            // determine what kind of closing tag is
            tagID = tagDetect(&input[pos + 1]);

            // Is this the closure of the last tag
            if (tagID == lastTag && (pos - openPos > MIN_TEXT_LENGTH || lastTag != Tags::Paragraph)) {

                // If two tags of same kind are used in sequence skip second
                if (lastAppended == lastTag) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Create new object in the array
                // Example:
                //     { tag: 2, content: "Some content" }
                node_obj = Object::New();
                node_obj->Set(tag_symbol, Integer::New(lastTag));
                node_obj->Set(data_symbol, String::New(
                    analyzer.getSummary(title,
                                        input.substr(openPos + (lastTag > 1 ? 3 : 2), pos - openPos - (lastTag > 1 ? 3 : 2) - 1),
                                        sentenceLimit).c_str()));

                nodes->Set(id++, node_obj);
                lastAppended = lastTag;
                continue;
            }

            // Clear useless tags
            input.erase(pos - 1, input.find('>', pos - 1) - pos + 2);
            break;

        // Sets a opening tag in the tag detect
        case Tags::Paragraph:
        case Tags::Heading:
            openPos = pos;
            lastTag = tagID;
            break;
        default:

            // Clear useless tags
            input.erase(pos - 1, input.find('>', pos - 1) - pos + 2);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Remove last element from array if its heading elements
    if (lastTag == Tags::Heading) {
        nodes->Delete(id - 1);
    }

    return nodes;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Need to find out what symbols are missing and where those symbols are defined ([nm](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) is your friend here)... then it is probably a problem of either linking those symbols (e.g. static library or *.o files) into your library... or making the shared library that defines available in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH when you run node.js or where node.js extension places its libraries.

Comment: @Deepsy, I have the same problem with another library. Did you find a solution?

Comment: How about trying using the Debug build? It should preserve symbols, I suppose.